# Ruby variable value set to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby/ Ruby on Rails. I wrote the below code to get a boolean value from api. The API call failed and it went to the **rescue** block. But for some reason, it set the value to true. I don't understand how that happened.

```
@is_attached = OnDeck.api.check_is_attached(@decision.application_number, current_user)
```

Api call / client wrapper Code

```
def check_is_attached(app_number, user)
   begin
        client.check_is_attached(app_number, user.auth_token)
   rescue OnDeckException::MerchantApiException => e
        Rails.logger.error("Caught exception #{e} while calling check_mbs_attached for app_number : #{app_number}")
 end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rails logger returns `true` on successfully logging:

```
[2] pry(main)> Rails.logger.error("Caught exception")
Caught exception
=> true
```

Because that is the last line executed in the method, that value is returned as ruby has implicit return.

Comment: Correct and you can still return whatever you wish from a rescue block.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rails.logger.error(string)
```

returns true as can be seen:

```
2.3.1 :002 > Rails.logger.error('foo')
foo
 => true
```